# Dates in SQLite3, with a twist (inaccurate dates)

Tags: sqlite, database-schema

I am working on genealogical software that stores its data in SQLite3 format. Everything works fine, except for one minor detail. Not in all cases is the accuracy of the birth or death dates (etc) available to the *exact* day. So I have the following accuracies:

- exact (YYYY-MM-DD)
- month (YYYY-MM)
- year (YYYY)
- year (YYYY+/-5)
- year (YYYY+/-10)
- year (YYYY+/-50)
- decade
- century

Now, assuming I store everything in a single column, I end up with a problem. Since SQLite3 has the [Julian Day function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) I was thinking to encode the accuracy in the fractional part of the `REAL` Julian Day (I don't need the hours anyway). That is fine, but it complicates the way `SELECT`s work, in fact it means that stuff I could otherwise offload to SQLite3 has to be implemented in application code.

What would be a reasonable method to store the inaccurate dates **and** be able to query them quickly?

Note: if it matters to anyone answering, the language used is Python, but I am asking in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing queries on those date values, the most common operation probably is to check whether a date might match another date.
For this, you always need the start and the end of the interval, so it would make sense to store these two values in the DB.
(Call them `Start`/`End` or `Min`/`Max` or `Earliest`/`Latest` or whatever makes sense.)

For example, to find people who might have been born one century ago:

```
... WHERE '1913-04-16' BETWEEN BirthDateMin AND BirthDateMax
```

Inequality comparisons can be done with one of the interval boundaries.
For example, to find people who might have been born more than one century ago:

```
... WHERE BirthDateMin < '1913-04-16'
```

Comment: also store as `TEXT` not `REAL`? Or will SQLite3 do some automagic conversion in such case?

Comment: `TEXT` is SQLite's default date format (it's the default used by its [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). You could just as well use Julian dates or Unix timestamps; the comparisons are the same.

Comment: thanks for the response. Will accept. Seems most logical and in contrast to Doug's solution it doesn't require the computation every time (i.e. computing the range from the date `+/-` the accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're storing date information, doesn't mean that the built-in date type is the right one for you.  Your data requirements (date inaccuracy) means that it's probably more accurate and better long-term to do some custom date-handling work, and avoid using the built-in date data types.

Comment: which method would be sensible, though? It makes sense to offload as much as possible to the SQLite3 engine, not implement it in application code. As I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use two columns. One column is the approximate date, as accurate as possible, in SQLite format. The second column is the accuracy of the date in days. If the date is absolutely accurate, the second column is zero. If only the month is known, the date would be mid month and the second column 15 days. Etc. Date comparisons can be done by comparing against the date +/- the accuracy column.

Comment: I can see merit in that idea, but wouldn't it also create one disadvantage: more uncertainty? Because the number of days in a decade or century would vary, so it would depend on the exact century, right?